# CSS include images relative to the location of the CSS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to indicate image path relative to the location of the .css file?

I have an image in a CSS style:

```
a[href $= '.pdf']:before {content:url(img/pdf.gif)}
```

I want to use the same CSS file in HTML pages located in the same directory (I include it as "mycss.css") and in sub-directories (I include this file as "../mycss.css").

In the latter case the images, obviously, are not found.

**EDIT: The images are found, so the rest of the question makes no sense.**

I do not want to use absolute paths, because with different URLs the same site is shown at different levels, as `mysite.example.com`, as `example.com/mysite`, and as `example.com/mycompany/mysite`.

Is there a way to indicate image path relative to the location of the .css file?

Or, conditionally include images depending on which ones exist (without confusing the browser with non-existent files). For example, it could be

```
a[href $= '.pdf']:before {content:url(img/pdf.gif) url(../img/pdf.gif)}
```

so that one of the two will be shown, but the browser might show a placeholder where the non-existent file was to be. So maybe it could be something like

```
if exists img/pdf.gif
    a[href $= '.pdf']:before {content:url(img/pdf.gif)}
else
    a[href $= '.pdf']:before {content:url(../img/pdf.gif)}
```

Comment: All image references in a stylesheet should be relative to the CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All image references in a stylesheet should be relative to the CSS file.

```
index.html
css/style.css
js/script.js
img/img-1.jpg
    img-2.jpg
    img-3.jpg
about/index.html
contact/index.html
```

Per the example above all images referencing the `img` directory in `style.css` would be `url('../img/*.jpg')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to generate the CSS with parameters on the fly using your server side code

```
Example: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mycssservlet?mypathlevel=2"> 
should generate the CSS on the fly with ../../img/myimg.png 
which is 2 time parent relative path
provided the server side program uses the proper content type
```

Otherwise use conditional CSS like LESS or SASS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call the CSS file correctly. Use a fixed absolute path:

```
http://static.example.com/css/style.css
```

And in the CSS file, give image path relative to CSS:

```css
background: url("../img/pic.png");
```

This applies if you have:

```
+ site
|--+ css
|  |-- styles.css
|  |-- plugin.css
|--+ img
|  |-- graphic.png
|  |-- img.png
```

Comment: including files with an absolute path really shouldn't be necessary.